# Does the retirement age for commercial airline pilots vary across the globe?

Tags: commercial-aviation, pilots, commercial-operations

Do the retirement age of commercial airlines pilot varies from country to country?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, they do vary between different countries. The international standard for regulations is created by [ICAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Civil_Aviation_Organization?wprov=sfti1), but member nations are free to deviate from ICAO rules and several do. ICAO currently limits retirement age to 60 for single-person crew, 65 for multi-person crew, and an exception to 70 for balloon or sailplane.

[EASA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Aviation_Safety_Agency?wprov=sfti1) did a study in 2019 in response to requests from countries to increase the age for single-person helicopter crews to 65. The link to the actual report is broken, but there is a summary [posted on the ICAO website](https://www.icao.int/safety/aviation-medicine/Documents/ASMA-ICAO%20meeting%20-Age%20limits%20Study_c.pdf). The rationale from these countries is that standard retirement age in those countries is 65. The report lists a few large agencies that deviate from the ICAO standards. Japan raised their limit to 68 for multi-crew ops. Canada, Australia and New Zealand have no age limit, the latter two indicating that it would be considered age discrimination.